# Android - getting picture from url without downloading

Tags: android, url, streaming

I there a way to getting picture(image) from URL without downloading? I use the code below to get streaming video and audio. But it doesn't work with picture.

```
public static void IntentPlayer(Context context, Uri uri, int mode){
    String type;
    switch(mode){
        case 1: type = "video/*"; break;
        case 2: type = "audio/*"; break;
        case 3: type = "image/*"; break;            
        default: return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();   
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);             
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);   
    context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

LogCat:

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://192.168.43.1:6789/mobile_base/Tulips.jpg typ=image/* flg=0x10000000 }
```

I don't want to download a file before I open it. I'll appreciate your answers. Thanks.

Comment: what are you attempting to do with the image? download the image, then show it within a view in the app?

Comment: show then how? with in the app, in a browser, what?

Comment: The method above shows native activity which depends on the file's type. If I pass to it local uri like `/mnt/sdcard/tulips.jpg` it shows me native image viewer. But as I said It doesn't work if I pass remote url like 'http://IP_Address:port/Resource...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the "native image viewer" to display an image from the web, but you can easily pass the url to the default browser, and it should automatically load it for you. You need to append an `http://` prefix for Android tell that you're trying to use the browser as the activity to handle that intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://scarlettjohansson.com/wholesome.png"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't suit me. I'm going to download image first.

Comment: Another option is to embed a WebView in a separate activity, and launch that.